# Undefined variable: keyword error in laravel 5 when using advanced where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, where-clause

I am using advanced where clause with parameter grouping. Here's the example

```
    $users = User::where('role', 'admin')
                   ->where(function ($query){
                       $query->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                             ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                             ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                             ->paginate($perPage);
                        });

return view('admin.index', compact('users'));
```

This part is giving me an error : **Undefined variable: keyword**

Then i searched on the net and found to to add use($keyword, $perPage) like this

```
$users = User::where('role', 'admin')
                   ->where(function ($query) use($keyword, $perPage){
                       $query->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                             ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                             ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                             ->paginate($perPage);
                        });
```

But then its showing me error in my view file

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::appends()**

**throw new BadMethodCallException("Call to undefined method {$className}::{$method}()");**

Here is the line causing error in index.blade.php

```
{{ $users->appends(['search' => Request::get('search')])->links("pagination::bootstrap-4") }}
```

This error was not present before adding use($keyword, $perPage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to the closure to make it work:

```
->where(function($query) use($keyword, $perPage) {
```

But I'm sure you want to put paginate outside the closure to make the query actually work:

```
User::where('role', 'admin')
    ->where(function($query) use($keyword) {
        $query->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
    })
    ->paginate($perPage);
```

Comment: @Raj add it to the closure too to fix the error. But I think you want to put `paginate()` outside the closure.

Answer (score 3):

You are `paginating` inside `closure`. Try `paginate` at the end like the following-

```
$users = User::where('role', 'admin')
               ->where(function ($query) use($keyword){
                   $query->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                         ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                         ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                         ;
                    })->paginate($perPage);
```